# send a variable to php with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How I can send `rowNumber` variable to `dataSource` php file in this code ?

```
function getData(dataSource, divID,rowNumber) 
{ 

if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(divID); 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource); 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
              XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
            { 
                obj.value = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
            } 
        } 

        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null); 
    }
}
```

PHP File (datasource):

```
<?php
  //mysql connection
  $result = mysql_query( 'CALL view_polls(`rowNumber`);' );
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row['title'];
?>
```

Comment: take a look on JQuery framework...it makes AJAX really easier:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getData(dataSource, divID,rowNumber) 
{ 

if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(divID); 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource + "?rownumber=" + rowNumber); 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
              XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
            { 
                obj.value = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
            } 
        } 

        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null); 
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['rownumber']) && is_numeric($_GET['rownumber'])) {
        $rowNumber = $_GET['rownumber'];
        //mysql connection
        $result = mysql_query( 'CALL view_polls(`' . $rowNumber . '`);' );
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row['title'];
  }
  else {
        echo "Error";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

in JavaScript:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource + '?rowNumber=' + rowNumber);
```

in PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query( 'CALL view_polls(`' . $_GET['rowNumber'] . '`);' );
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the query and make sure that the query string rowNumber indeed exists: `if (isset($_GET['rowNumber']) && is_numeric($_GET['rowNumber'])) { ... }`!

Comment: Thank You @Sascha Galley very much